# Макрос для excel - VBA (гиперссылка)

Tags: excel, vba

Помогите пожалуйста написать макрос для excel. Нужно, что бы при наведении на гиперссылку отображалось содержимое папки (название всех файлов). Или при вставке гиперссылки в ячейки создавалась еще 1 строчка, в которой бы перечислялись все файлы которые находятся в папке.
В vba совсем ничего не знаю. Но этот макрос мне нужен. Извините, если задал тупой вопрос.

---

Вот примерно, что я хотел. Но мне теперь нужно, что бы выдавалась ссылки на сами документы в папке. (И почему то после того как задаю диапазон у меня вылезают ошибки. То есть тут всего 1 ячейка для ввода ссылки и 1 ячейка для выдачи результата, а строк у меня к примеру будет 100)

```
Sub vvv()
Range("B2").Select
Range("B2").Clear
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ShowFolderList(Range("A2").Text)
Range("B2").Select


End Sub

Function ShowFolderList(folderspec)
Dim fso, f, f1, fc, s
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.GetFolder(folderspec)
Set fc = f.Files
For Each f1 In fc
    s = s & f1.Name & vbNewLine
Next
ShowFolderList = s
End Function
```

Comment: Задача для фриланс-площадки. "Помогите" поразумевает подсказки по проблеме... Но в чем помощь? Здесь: "сделайте мне полностью".

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что создан другой вопрос, дублирующий, в котором четче описан вопрос.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/739172/Гиперссылки-vba